# Access localStorage property, method returning null

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So, `getSuppliers()` returns `null` despite the existence of: `token`.

```
class Supplier {
    constructor() {
        this.getSuppliers();
    }

    getToken() {
        const jwtTokenString = localStorage.getItem('status.authorisation.token');
        const jwtToken = jwtTokenString ? JSON.parse(jwtTokenString) : null;
        return jwtToken;
    }

    getSuppliers() {
        console.log(this.getToken());
    }
}
```

[image]

What I'm trying:

```
getToken() {
    const jwtTokenString = localStorage.getItem('authorisation.token');
    const jwtToken = jwtTokenString ? JSON.parse(jwtTokenString) : null;
    return jwtToken;
}

getToken() {
        const jwtTokenString = localStorage.getItem('authorisation.token');
        const jwtToken = jwtTokenString ? jwtTokenString : null;
        return jwtToken;
    }

getToken() {
        const jwtTokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const jwtToken = jwtTokenString ? jwtTokenString : null;
        return jwtToken;
    }
```

What's the correct way to retrieve the token?

Comment: you don't show what you `setItem` ... so - whatever key you use to `setItem` that's the one to use to `getItem` - `the existence of: token.` where does it exist in `localStorage`? That looks like it exists in some request response - which is completely unrelated to `localStorage`

Comment: status.authorisation.token

above code u ue this and blow code you use this 
authorisation.token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the localstorage like an object `localStorage.getItem('authorisation.token');` you should call `.getItem('the name like you set it')` and then when you `parse` it then you can access it like an object.

```js
  getToken() {
        const jwtTokenString = localStorage.getItem('the name when is set');
        const jwtToken = jwtTokenString ? JSON.parse(jwtTokenString) : null;
        return jwtToken.authorisation.token;
    }
```

If you want to access it like an object for example you can do this.

```js
localStorage.setItem('token', 'sometoken')

console.log(localStorage.token) // sometoken
```